# What is the exact value of voltage at T in square wave form?

Tags: voltage, waveform, graph

[image]

at t=0s v=1V;

T=5ms v=1,0,-1? which one? looking at graph.

Comment: None.  The best description from this low res. image is at t=5ms the signal goes sharply from +1 to -1V

Comment: what do you mean by `T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were "real" you could look at a way shorter timescale you would see a slope. You could then find a voltage for every point in time. For this "ideal" graph it's simply a mathematical discontinuity, there is no value.

Comment: I think that mathematically it's defined as 0.5 at the discontinuity